# Removing new line feed

Tags: python, json

I am in the process of downloading data from firebase, exporting it into a json. After this I am trying to upload it into bigquery but I need to remove the new line feed for big query to accept it.

This is how I receive it from firebase.

```
{
"ConnectionTime": 730669.644775033, 
"objectId": "eHFvTUNqTR", 
"CustomName": "Relay Controller", 
"FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", 
"DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", 
"PeripheralType": 9, 
"updatedAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z", 
"Model": "DF Bluno", 
"HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", 
"Serial": "0123456789", 
"createdAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z", 
"Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
{
"ConnectionTime": 702937.7616419792, 
"objectId": "uYuT3zgyez", 
"CustomName": "Relay Controller", 
"FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", 
"DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", 
"PeripheralType": 9, 
"updatedAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", 
"Model": "DF Bluno", 
"HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", 
"Serial": "0123456789", 
"createdAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", 
"Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
```

This is how I need it but can not figure out how to do this besides manually doing it.

```
{ "AppName": "DataWorks","ConnectionTime": 126.7699910402298,"CustomName": "28888               ","DeviceID": "DC0798BD-EDB5-491B-8744-526C98FCDCA1","FirmwareRevision": "1.98","HardwareRevision" : "null","Manufacturer": "Transducers Direct LLC","Model": "TDWLB200010013      ","PeripheralType" : "5","PeripheralUUID": "5BB621A7-4AB8-69CF-7E0B-318547DFCF6D","Serial": "0000028888","createdAt": "1970-01-01T02:14:52.142Z" } { "AppName" : "DataWorks","ConnectionTime" : 3922.534584999084,"CustomName" : "28888               ","DeviceID" : "DC0798BD-EDB5-491B-8744-526C98FCDCA1","FirmwareRevision" : "1.98","HardwareRevision" : "null","Manufacturer" : "Transducers Direct LLC","Model" : "TDWLB200010013      ","PeripheralType" : "5","PeripheralUUID" : "5BB621A7-4AB8-69CF-7E0B-318547DFCF6D","Serial" : "0000028888","createdAt" : "1970-01-01T03:35:51.795Z" }
```

I am using python to load the json, read it and then write a new one but can not figure out the right code. Thank you!

here is the outline for my python code

```
import json
with open('nospacetest.json', 'r') as f:
  data_json=json.load(f)

#b= to file afte code for no line breaks is added

with open('testnoline.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump=(b, outfile)
```

Comment: I dont know why only the first data set is in code style but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: You don't need json for that

Comment: I need it to be in a json to upload it to bigquery. or it could be in a csv but the same problem occurs.

Comment: add some python code so that someone can help.

Comment: i added my outline to import the json save the file to a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace new line with anything using str.replace():

```
new_json_str = old_json_str.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Comment: This is what I have. Everything in the json is not a string though           
    'import json
    with open('nospacetest.json', 'r') as f:
      data_json=json.load(f)
 
    new_json = data_json.replace('\n', '')

    with open('testnoline.json', 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump('new_json_str', outfile)'

Comment: There is nothing like json data type in python. It's either string or dictionary. you can interconvert them.

Comment: @W.Stephens eliminate `json.load` entirely, just load the raw json as a string value and then strip the newlines out of that.